# Is it possible to use R on an iPad?

Tags: r

I am new to coding and I am attempting to learn about [R](https://www.r-project.org) using online resources. I am wondering how to use R from an iPad when I’m away from a desktop/laptop (or if this is feasible at all)?

I also don’t know much about operating systems, or the differences between a Mac and an iPad (particularly differences that would affect software installation). So I’m thinking it will be quite difficult for me to learn to use R from an iPad if it’s at all possible. But if someone else happens to have done it and is willing to post instructions, I would give it a shot.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is basically:

> “Is it possible to use R on an iPad?”

And the answer to that is a simple:

### No.

While you are well intentioned in your post, from a basic operating system there is no way you can program on *any* iOS device since you won’t be able to ever selfie-install tools or get to the command line to install R to begin with.

Some might say you could do this by using the iPad to remotely connect to another machine—such as a MacBook or a Mac mini and such—but that is really not a solution. You would simply be remotely accessing a real computer in a kludgy way. If you want to use R, you need a real macOS computer… Or Windows… But you asked for Mac so I will say… Mac.

Comment: The sandbox actually allows much of what you say isn't possible. Also, I'll make an answer that explains how to use networking to get to an OS where someone might be more comfortable running R. Pythonista is one such app that installs an entire framework for data processing and runs very well on iOS for adding packages, interacting with the network (when it's available) and doing real work. Even data science work.

Comment: I’ll add some links to an answer here. I use a USB-C hub with my iPads and full wired keyboards. There are a handful of apps that really work well keyboard only. I don’t disagree at all with your main point  iOS is no way an open computer OS  without sandbox restrictions. Based on software needs, iPad won’t be the correct tool for many people. However, the list of things iPad can’t do is eroding and it’s far better than Macs for many things at this point.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, for up to R 4.2.1, there is [R Analyst](https://apps.apple.com/app/r-analyst/id1173749340).

Limitation: cannot install additional packages.